# Filename coming from other files in same folder

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder with seismogram files. Its format correspont to particle movement in three dimensions (HHE correponds to E-W, HHN correponds to N-S and HHZ corrsponds to vertical particle movement). The script to merge these three components in a file is the following:

```
from obspy.core import read

threechannels = read('*.HHE.sac')

threechannels1 = read('*.HHN.sac')

threechannels2 = read('*.HHZ.sac')

tc=threechannels+threechannels1+threechannels2

tc.write('tc.mseed',format='mseed')
```

The output file is named **tc.mseed** because I don´t know how to do that the name file will be the same as the three files that the script use to merge. ¿Is possible to do this on one way?

I show you the directory structure and how I want to obtainn it. The following example is for only one group of files.

```
  2010_09_23_05_28_35.HR01.HHE.sac
  2010_09_23_05_28_35.HR01.HHN.sac
  2010_09_23_05_28_35.HR01.HHZ.sac

  2010_09_23_05_28_35.HR01.mseed
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: WElcome to SO, seems liek there are multiple questions, please break it down into single questions. This helps future readers to also find solutions. Otherwise we would only help you to solve a very specific question where it is very unlikely for future readers to have the same problem. One way would be to ask multiple question each one very short and very specific.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I will try to be more specific and I will do only one question by editing the post. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You also could propably remove the whole particle movement part. Because your question essentially is about creating paths for files in a folder dynamically not about particle movement. The Question title is already ok, but could be improved with something like: "Filename coming from other files in same folder".

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will follow it for the title but not for the introduction. I think that is indispensable tell why there are three files to convert in one file. If you think that I am wrong please say me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No it is alright, just be aware for future questions, simpler is usually better. Since people get points for answering and getting upvoted it is more likely to receive answer to questions which can help future readers (since they might also upvote both question and answer).

Comment: Perfect. I´ll be aware for the future. Thanks for your advices. I will looking for the simplicity in the nest questions. Thanks another time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
path_folder = r"D:\test"

# get list of all files in folder which end on .sac
lst_of_filenames = [name for name in os.listdir(path_folder) if (name.endswith(".sac")]
# only get a unqiue filename without any ending
# r"" means raw string
lst_of_filenames_cleaned = [name.rstrip(r".HHE.sac").rstrip(r".HHN.sac").rstrip(r".HHZ.sac") for name in lst_of_filenames]
# get each filename only once (remove duplicates)
lst_of_filenames_cleaned = list(set(lst_of_filenames_cleaned))
```

After you got each possible filename you now can plug in your script with a loop:

```
# use your script with a loop
from obspy.core import read

for filename in lst_of_filenames_cleaned:
    print(filename)
    threechannels = read(os.path.join(path_folder, filename + '.HHE.sac'))
    
    threechannels1 = read(os.path.join(path_folder, filename + '.HHN.sac')
    
    threechannels2 = read(os.path.join(path_folder, filename + '.HHZ.sac')
    
    tc=threechannels+threechannels1+threechannels2
    
    tc.write(os.path.join(path_folder, filename + '.mseed',format='mseed')
```

Comment: Thanks. I´ll try it and comment you.

Comment: Ohhhh. It worked perfectly. I achieved the results that I was looking for. Many thanks. I will vote your answer as the solution.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Could you also upvote? (correct answer +15, upvote +10) Happy Coding!

Comment: Don't worry, I mean you don't have to, just would be nice. It is the up button looking like a triangle.